# 3D plane rotation about a line

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, 3d, rotations

In three dimensional space we have a plane and a line. These can be oriented in any way. The plane is rotated about the line by n degrees, meaning that originally the position of the plane is fixed to the line and the line is rotated along with it's own axis. How do I form the equation of the rotated plane if I know the equations for the original unrotated plane and the line?

For an example, let's assume the plane is $2\vec{i} + 3\vec{j} - 4\vec{k} + 15 = 0$ and our line is represented by the vector $3\vec{i} - 2\vec{j} + 5\vec{k}$. Let's rotate the plane 25 degrees. How is this done?

Answer (score 3):

Apply [Rodrigues' formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula) to a triple of points $P, Q, R$ on the plane; that'll give you three new points, $P', Q', R'$ and you can compute the new plane as
$$
(X - Q') \cdot [(P' - Q') \times (R' - Q')] = 0.
$$

As an alternative: 
First, write your plane equation in the form 
$$
\newcommand{\vv}{{\mathbf v}}
$$
$$
X \cdot \vv + d = 0
$$
In your example, $\vv = [2, 3, -4]$, and $d = 15$, so the equation is 
$$
X \cdot \begin{bmatrix}2\\3\\4\end{bmatrix} + 15 = 0.
$$

Some multiple $c\vv$ of $\vv$ lies on the plane; to see what value of $c$ works, we plug in:
$$
(c\vv) \cdot vv + 15 = 0\\
c (\vv \cdot vv) + 15 = 0\\
c (29) + 15 = 0 \\
c = -\frac{15}{29}.
$$
In general, let
$$
c = -\frac{\vv \cdot \vv}{d};
$$
then the point $c\vv$ lies on the line. Let's call that point $P$.

Now apply Rodrigues' formula,
$$
\mathbf{v}_\mathrm{rot} = \mathbf{v} \cos\theta + (\mathbf{k} \times \mathbf{v})\sin\theta
  + \mathbf{k} (\mathbf{k} \cdot \mathbf{v}) (1 - \cos\theta).
$$

to the normal vector $\vv$ of the plane to get a new vector $\vv'$.
If we *also* apply it to the point $P$, we'll get a new point that lies on the rotated plane. But since $P$ is a multiple of $\vv$, $P'$ will be the same multiple of $\vv'$. After a bit of fiddling, the result is that the "d" value remains the same, so

the equation of the new plane is
$$
(X \cdot \vv') + d = 0,
$$
where $\vv'$ is obtained by Rodrigues' formula, and $d$ is the constant term in the original plane equation.